# creating dbthreadpools in java play

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, oracle, playframework

This is in relation to question [in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034437/how-to-create-db-threadpool-in-play-java-and-make-db-queries-with-this-pool/39046599#39046599) .

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

ExecutorService ec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
public CompletionStage<Result> test {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return Ebean.createSqlQuery(sqlQuery).findList();
    }, ec) // <-- 'ec' is the ExecutorService you want to use
    .thenApply(rows -> {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return ok(f(rows));
        //do lot of computation over rows
    )}
}
```

Does the program use default executioncontext to do the computation f(rows) or use the execution context ec?

If I want to set the settings similar to akka exection context like

```
my-context {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 20.0
    parallelism-max = 200
  }
}
```

How do I do it?